# Counting elements in a matrix r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

got another question for you. How can I create automaticly the dataframe "result" out of my starting position.

For example: I have to select every row with the element "E3" in it, and summarize the corresponding number of it.

I'd like to have a result like my dataframe "result". E3 -> 100+200+300 = 600

```
#starting position
v1 <- c("E1","E2","E3")
v2 <- c("E2","E3",NA)
v3 <- c("E3","E5",NA)
number <- c(100, 200, 300)
test <- data.frame(cbind(v1,v2,v3,number))

#result
index <- c("E1","E2","E3","E5")
total <- c(100, 300, 600, 300)
result <- data.frame(cbind(index,total))
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but there is no need to use `cbind` in your data frame. `data.frame(index,total)` will do.

Comment: For "E5" I get the value 200 in the result. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with base `R`:

```
M <- cbind(v1=c("E1","E2","E3"),
           v2=c("E2","E3",NA),
           v3=c("E3","E5",NA))
number <- c(100, 200, 300)

index <- c("E1","E2","E3","E5")
sapply(index, function(x) sum(number[apply(M==x, 1, any)], na.rm=TRUE))
# > sapply(index, function(x) sum(number[apply(M==x, 1, any)], na.rm=TRUE))
#  E1  E2  E3  E5 
# 100 300 600 200
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but it doesnt work on my computer...
Error in apply(M == x, 1, any) : object 'M' not found

Comment: `M <- cbind(v1, v2, v3)` I used this matrix (instead of a dataframe).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
  gather(key = "col", value = "val", -number) %>% 
  group_by(val) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)


# A tibble: 5 x 2
  val   number
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 E1      100.
2 E2      300.
3 E3      600.
4 E5      200.
5 NA      600.
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(total ~., data.frame(index = unlist(test[1:3]), 
       total = rep(test$number, each = 3)), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#   index total
#1    E1   100
#2    E2   300
#3    E3   600
#4    E5   300
```

#### data

```
test <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,number)
```